# How do you set up golang on windows with the header files for goav

Tags: windows, go, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile goav on Windows and I've got quite far
I've compiled the ffmpeg libraries in MSYS2 and linked the packages with:

```
set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=%~dp0FFmpeg\libavformat;%~dp0FFmpeg\libavcodec;%~dp0FFmpeg\libavutil;%~dp0FFmpeg\libswresample;
```

which has worked!

However, here's the problem now:

```
# github.com/giorgisio/goav/avcodec
source\src\github.com\giorgisio\goav\avcodec\avcodec.go:14:34: fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory
 //#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
```

When compiling, Golang can't find the avformat.h (and I assume the other ffmpeg header files, but compilation terminated).

How do I tell go where these files are? I've checked and they are in the folders described in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH, but I guess it's not looking for them there.

Side note: I see that on linux-debian based systems I just have to do a `apt-get install libavformat-dev` but I want to compile on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to set the CGO_CFLAGS environment variable before building to tell the compiler where the include files are for ffmpeg:

```
@set CGO_CFLAGS=-IC:\path\to\FFmpeg\
```

... My project is still not building, but that error isn't showing up anymore

Comment: I'm now getting these errors: src\github.com\giorgisio\goav\avcodec\codecs.go:57:48: could not determine kind of name for C.AV_CODEC_ID_ADPCM_VIMA_DEPRECATED